# Why does node-gyp (and other stuff) require Visual Studio?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-c++, node-gyp

node-gyp isn't the first thing I've run into requiring it, but this seems odd. I assume this has something to do with building executables or plugins or whatever but is there no dependency smaller than a complete version of Visual Studio or VS Express that can fit the bill? I though you could actually write, build and run .net apps without a copy of VS if you really wanted to. I ask with intent to at least learn some C++ or whatever else it takes while attempting to address the problem although I imagine it's nontrivial if Joyent couldn't find a way around it easily enough.

Note: I'm not having a problem with node-gyp as a node dependency but Windows users with that issue should try updating node by downloading from the web and reinstalling from that exe file before doing any of the other madness out there that I narrowly dodged. They seem to have fixed the 2010-only issue without really announcing it very loudly and npm doesn't really work when attempting to update itself and Node on Windows.

Comment: It needs Visual Studio for the C++ compiler and include files; nothing to do with .Net.

Comment: So you can't get the compiler independently anymore?

Comment: I don't think the C++ compiler was ever available standalone.

Comment: Looks like it was available with win C++ SDK which I assume is smaller than a VS Express install.

Comment: I forgot about that.  It ought to be possible for gyp to use that, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, note the past tense :( It just doesn't feel "node-thonic" to be downloading an entire IDE as a dependency for a core module like that but I noticed UE4 requiring it for certain things too. Why does MS hate our hard drive space?

Comment: I have issued the feedback on uservoice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6742251-make-c-c-compiler-cl-exe-independent-of-ide. Please vote everyone to draw their attention! Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It works without Visual Studio, but you'll need to install Windows SDK:

1. Get Windows SDK from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442
2. Use "SDK command line" shortcut on your desktop to launch npm install

I found this solution here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-138276692

Comment: Well that's true now so fair enough. (I dont' believe this was an option at the time of asking)

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**
You can download latest build tools [here](https://aka.ms/buildtools).
Recent announcements [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-visual-studio-build-tools/) and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/visual-studio-build-tools-now-include-the-vs2017-and-vs2015-msvc-toolsets/).

*Original answer:*
Finally Microsoft is providing much better solution. A standalone Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 Technical Preview.
More info [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/11/02/announcing-visual-c-build-tools-2015-standalone-c-tools-for-build-environments.aspx)

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @JohnWeisz thanks, I have fixed links and updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

## EDIT:

> Please note that the official [Node.js for Windows installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) can now automatically install the required tools. That's likely a much better option than the module listed here (`windows-build-tools`).

---

## ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I was able to run node-gyp 0.8.x on Windows 10 **without Visual Studio** using the [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools).

Install the build tools with this one-liner. Start PowerShell as Administrator and run:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools
```

And wait for the installation to complete.

Comment: Tried that but it wasn't working. I gave up and installed visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Node itself and other "close to core" libraries, like node-gyp, require a C++ compiler. In most dev environments on Windows this will be Visual Studio in combination with Python. However you could also use MinGW or Cygwin with `gcc` installed.

The experience of doing stuff with `gcc` directly would compare to compiling .NET code on the Windows platform. However `gcc` doesn't feel native on Windows.

Comment: Not sure this would have worked. There was something MS-specific in terms of packaging on windows that made having the ms c++ compiler necessary IIRC.