# How to find node-gyp dependency (..or any dependency) in npm project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, node-gyp

I am going through unimaginable frustration trying to get a project to run (ie. by calling **'npm install'**) that always trips over **node-gyp**. I am on windows so I need to install python and something like Visual Studio.

Long story short... I do not want to have a dependency on a festering pile of s*** like Visual Studio, so I want to see if somehow this node-gyp could somehow be optional, or be gotten rid of.

Now if I open my package.json file I find these dependencies.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-stylus": "^0.7.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.8.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-nunjucks-html": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.0.6",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "jeet": "^6.1.2",
    "kouto-swiss": "^0.11.13",
    "minimist": "^1.1.3",
    "rupture": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-install": "^0.6.0"
  }
```

I can see the dependency tree of each of these packages by going here :

http://npm.anvaka.com/#/

However if I go through every single one of these dependencies I cannot see the node-gyp dependency anywhere for any of these.

Is there something I don't understand about dependencies? What uses node-gyp? And why?

Answer (score 4):

node-gyp is required for native C/C++ Add ons as mentioned in the doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)

The dependencies are built on each target platform. For windows platforms it requires visual studio as mentioned in their [installation notes here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation)

`node-gyp` is itself not mentioned in `package.json` (probably because it requires global installation) so, you will have to manually see if any of dependencies or its nested dependencies are using native c/c++ add ons either by their repo or downloaded source code or the npm install log itself. One way could be in npm_modules folder search for file `binding.gyp` or `.cc/.cpp` files, and you should be able to locate the culprit npm module.

Answer (score 1):

[`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) lists **installed** dependencies in your project. `npm ls node-gyp` will limit node-gyp's sub-tree.

[`npm-remote-ls`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-remote-ls) lists all dependencies of a remote package. You an manually go through or use `grep`

I created [`findep`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/findep) which is a lot faster than both (for this purpose). It can check your local project, an external npm package, or even a remote github project, and has a `--greedy` option that stops as soon as it finds the specified dependency.

```bash
# Checks if current project has a 'node-gyp' dependency
findep node-gyp

# Checks if the npm package 'node-sass' has a 'node-gyp' dependency
findep node-gyp -e node-sass

# Greedily checks if the project 'AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter' has at least one of these dependencies including "devDependencies":
$ findep he mime lodash ms -GDr -e AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter
Looking for [he, mime, lodash, ms] in AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter...
Found 16 dependencies that use [he, mime, lodash, ms]:
assets-webpack-plugin > lodash
string-replace-loader > lodash
karma-coverage > lodash
```

Answer (score 1):

To find its dependencies

```
npm ls node-gyp
```

Answer (score 0):

`node-gyp` is used for compiling native addon modules for node. Have you had a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation), particularly the windows info? Also, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959640/why-does-node-gyp-and-other-stuff-require-visual-studio) for a way around the Visual Studio requirement